# Is "it's" or "its" possessive?

Tags: possessives, it-its-itself

For a very long time now I've been using "it's" as the possessive form for "it". There have been some people that have said "its" is the possessive form, but I'm not sure if that's true. "It's" seems a lot more like a possessive.

Is "it's" or "its" the possessive form of "it"?

Comment: It’s definitely *its*.

Comment: Yes.  "Its" is possessive.

Comment: Please refer to one of the "related" questions listed on the right side.

Comment: I'm flagging this as off-topic ("no research / ELL"). Hi PSVM, did you consult a dictionary before you asked here? Our [Help Centre](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) says "Be sure to [mention the research you've done](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/5043) and what you're still hoping to learn!" For further guidance, see [ask] and take the EL&U **[Tour]** :-)

Comment: Review your basic grammar, dude. Anyway, unless you were an etymologist, historically it was indeed *it's*, as in *it* + possessive marker *'s*, but now the only correct form is *its*.

Comment: @Vun-HughVaw *It* + genitive ending *s*, almost certainly (according to OED); but no mention of an apostrophe, akin to other possessive pronouns like *his, hers, ours, theirs.* Similarly *hern,* after *mine, thine, yourn* and the like. Pronouns have never had apostrophes, and it's possible that the possessive apostrophe came from forms like "The Lord of Salisbury his Pavan".

Comment: @AndrewLeach https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/when-to-use-it's-vs-its Probably because its didn't start out like other possessive pronouns which dated way way back to Proto-Germanic. It appears to be a much later coinage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'It's' is the short form of 'It is' and 'its' is possessive. 
Edit: Apparently it's is also contracted form of it has. now the answer is complete I guess.

Comment: Incomplete. **It's** is also the contracted form of ***it has*** as in *"My car, it's seen better days"* and *"it's got a flat tyre"*

Comment: I'm not a native english speaker but I have never seen anywhere it's used instead of it has.

Comment: You've seen it, *and* heard it, you just didn't realise that it was a present perfect construction. [**It's been** a hard day's night, and I've been working....](https://www.google.com/search?num=20&ei=r9FAXI2bMsvWkwWf3JbADQ&q=%22It%27s+been+a+hard+day%27s+night%22&oq=%22It%27s+been+a+hard+day%27s+night%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i7i30l5j0l5.17335.20702..20954...0.0..0.108.205.1j1......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71.k8oWbI8VpsE)

Comment: yes I might have heard it but I just assumed that they were using it incorrectly...I never heard it from people that I expect to use correct grammer.